# knockout string comparison in if data-binding

Tags: knockout.js

The `category` variable is defined as `ko.observable()` and child value should be changed according to `category` value.
Below if statement always returns false.

```
<!-- ko if: $parent.category == "Electronics"-->
   <div>abc</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

the if satement below also always returns false:

```
<span data-bind="if: $parent.category == 'Electronics'">
   <div>abc</div>
</span>
```

How to do comparison in data-binding with hard-code values?

Comment: If you want to use that syntax, use something like this. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/05/20/knockout-es5-a-plugin-to-simplify-your-syntax/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

KO observables are functions and to get their value inside expressions you need to call them without any argument e.g.: `$parent.category()`

So you need to change your code to:

```
<!-- ko if: $parent.category() == "Electronics"-->
   <div>abc</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

In your original code you are comparing the observable function (`$parent.category`) and not its value with `"Electronics"` that is why its always false.